# Windows pintool mismatch between call/ret instructions

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, callstack, intel-pin

So i've been trying to write a pintool that monitors call/ret instructions but i've noticed that threre was a significant inconsistency between the two. For example ret instructions without previous call.

I've run the tool in a console application from which i got the following logs showing this inconsistency (this is an example, there are more inconsistencies like the one listed below in the other call/ret instructions):

```
1. Call from ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x69, expected to return to 7ff88f00502a
2. RETURN to 7ff88f00502a
//call from ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode+0x1ac which is supposed to return at 7ff88f049385 is missing (the previous instruction)
3. RETURN to 7ff88f049385 (ntdll!LdrpInitializeNode+0x1b1)
```

The above are the first 3 log entries for the call/ret instructions. As one can see, the monitoring started a bit late, at the call found at `ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x69`, it returned to the expected address but then returned to 7ff88f049385 without first tracking the call found in the previous instruction.

Any ideas of what could be the fault?

The program is traced with `INS_AddInstrumentFunction` with a callback that more or less does:

```
if INS_IsCall(ins) INS_InsertCall(ins,...
if INS_IsRet(ins) INS_InsertCall(ins,...
```

I've tried the same program on Linux which worked as expected, without any mismatch.
Any ideas of the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: So those calls are the outer-most levels of call/ret in the whole program?  I think you're saying that your pin tool seems to have missed the very first `call` in the whole program, but other than that everything matches?

Comment: What i have listed above is just the first three call/ret instructions. The program has a lot more and there are more inconsistencies similar with the one listed above. Now whether a call was missed or not, i am not exactly sure.